# Filter iframe data output

Tags: html, iframe, filtering

Is there a way of filtering the data of an iframe output?

For example I'll do an iframe on http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/python-tutorials/python-from-scratch-creating-a-dynamic-website/ and I only want to print the div with tutorial_image class. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iframes sourced from other domains are subject to the **Same Origin Policy** - this prevents the host page from messing with them. This is a security feature that can be turned off in your browser settings -- but you cannot control this for other users.